Streamlit multiple Checkboxes with one allowed Selection
I want to make multiple checkboxes in streamlit like in this image below.
Screenshot Checkboxes
But I want the behavior, that just on checkbox can be selected. That means, if a checkbox is selected and you select another one that cancels out the first selection.
I also tried it out with st.radio, but the problem there is that I can't have no selection and it doesn't fulfill my use case.

I would try to use on_check in checkbox to run code which unchecks other checkboxes. Maybe it would work also with radio to uncheck it when it clicked second time

the simplest can be add another radio with  show all or show nothing

The simplest could be to use st.radio with another radio Show All or Show Nothing
With st.checkbox you could use on_change to run code which set False on other checkboxes.
Every checkbox needs unique key, and it has to send this key to on_check.
It also need to keep all keys on list - to use it late to uncheck all other checkboxes

Minimal working code:
import streamlit as st

def on_change_checkbox(current_key):
    #print('current_key:', current_key)

    # uncheck all checkboxes except current
    for key in checkbox_keys:
        if key != current_key:
            st.session_state[key] = False

checkbox_keys = []

key = 'cb pdf'
st.checkbox('Select PDF', key=key, on_change=on_change_checkbox, args=(key,))
checkbox_keys.append(key)

key = 'cb database'
st.checkbox('Select Database', key=key, on_change=on_change_checkbox, args=(key,))
checkbox_keys.append(key)

key = 'cb something else'
st.checkbox('Select Something Else', key=key, on_change=on_change_checkbox, args=(key,))
checkbox_keys.append(key)


Example which use dictionary with lists to group checkboxes
#!/usr/bin/env python3

"""
# author: Bartlomiej "furas" Burek (https://blog.furas.pl)
# date: 2024.06.20
# [python - Streamlit multiple Checkboxes with one allowed Selection - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78647325/streamlit-multiple-checkboxes-with-one-allowed-selection/78648360#78648360)
"""

import streamlit as st

def on_change_checkbox(current_key, group):
    print('current_key:', current_key, group)

    # uncheck all checkboxes except current
    for key in checkbox_keys[group]:
        if key != current_key:
            st.session_state[key] = False

checkbox_keys = {}

# ----

st.text('Source')

checkbox_keys['Source'] = []

key = 'cb source pdf'
st.checkbox('Select PDF', key=key, on_change=on_change_checkbox, args=(key, 'Source'))
checkbox_keys['Source'].append(key)

key = 'cb source database'
st.checkbox('Select Database', key=key, on_change=on_change_checkbox, args=(key, 'Source'))
checkbox_keys['Source'].append(key)

key = 'cb source something else'
st.checkbox('Select Something Else', key=key, on_change=on_change_checkbox, args=(key, 'Source'))
checkbox_keys['Source'].append(key)

# ----

st.text('Target')

checkbox_keys['Target'] = []

key = 'cb target pdf'
st.checkbox('Select PDF', key=key, on_change=on_change_checkbox, args=(key, 'Target'))
checkbox_keys['Target'].append(key)

key = 'cb target database'
st.checkbox('Select Database', key=key, on_change=on_change_checkbox, args=(key, 'Target'))
checkbox_keys['Target'].append(key)

key = 'cb target something else'
st.checkbox('Select Something Else', key=key, on_change=on_change_checkbox, args=(key, 'Target'))
checkbox_keys['Target'].append(key)



With st.radio you may only add button which assigns None and this will clear selection.
import streamlit as st

def clear_radio(current_key):
    #print('current_key:', current_key)

    # uncheck radio
    st.session_state[current_key] = None


key = 'r select'
st.radio('Select:', key=key, index=None, options=['Select PDF', 'Select Database', 'Select Something Else'])
st.button('Clear', on_click=clear_radio, args=(key,))

